# How to ping each IP from rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ping

I am populating my datagridview from a dropdownlist, except for one column which is named Status that I statically put in there.
After it is populated I want to ping each device listed and update the Status column pending whether the item is pinging or not by pressing a button
I think I am close as it does what I want it to do, except that it's not reporting devices that aren't pinging.
Below is my code as well as a link to a screen shot of the application.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridView1Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {



                    //currQty += dataGridView1Row.Cells["qty"].Value;
                    var url = dataGridView1Row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    int timeout = 500;
                    Ping ping = new Ping();


                    PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(url, timeout);
                    PingReply result = null;
                    IPStatus status;

                    result = pingreply;
                    status = result.Status;

                    if (status != IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable)
                    {
                        dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Value = "Online";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        dataGridView1Row.Cells[0].Value = "Offline";
                    }


                
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: You probably need to share more information for us to get a better idea of what you are doing.  Are you doing this on the UI thread?  You probably want to do this asynchronously; however, it appears that these APIs predate `Task` and async/await. That will complicate your life. For what it's worth, the five lines between the `pint.Send` and the `status = result.Status;` can probably be coalesced into two lines.

Comment: Are you updating / refreshing your grid after the changes are made?

Comment: I don't update the grid. Only the status column changes from being blank to either online or offline after the button press is made.

Comment: @Flydog57 `var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync([IpAddress], [TimeOut], [Buffer]);`

Comment: @Jimi: You handy to have around.  I looked at `SendAsync` (which is a pre-`Task` call).  Not sure why I didn't look at `SendPingAsync`.

Comment: @Flydog57 The usual, *another pair of eyes* :) Btw, that code should test `reply.Status != IPStatus.Success`, since failures can be of different types, not just `DestinationHostUnreachable`; for example, `TimedOut`, quite probable given the `500` timeout set. A TimeOut should reschedule a Ping, `Offline` is not the *right* result in this case.

Comment: @FlyDog57 I tried your line: var reply = await ping.SendPingAsync([IpAddress], [TimeOut], [Buffer]);, but everything after =  is all in red.

Comment: @Jimi I tried this reply.Status != IPStatus.Success and this worked exactly how I needed it too. Now I just gotta wrap it in a loop to constant ping.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your actual model from how you show the data in your model to the operator.

In other words: don't edit the cells in your DataGridView, put your data in the DataSource of the DataGridView.

Somehow you get the sequence of `IPAddresses` that you want to show. I'm not sure if the operator types the `Description` after you show them, or whether the Description is already known when you fetch the IPAddresses.

```
class IpTestAddress
{
    public IPAddress IpAddress {get; set;}  // maybe you have a string?
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

And you need a method to get the sequence of Test IP Addresses that must be shown. It does not matter whether you fetch them from a file, or check all your devices in your network, whatever. Somewhere you have a method:

```
IEnumerable<IpTestAddress> GetIpTestAddresses() {...}
```

Now assuming you have such a method. After you've fetched the IPAddresses you want to show them: one IpTestAddress per row.

Apparently you also have a method to get the Ping status:

```
string GetPingStatus(IPAddress ipAddress) {...}
```

The code of this method is not part of your question.

Apparently you want to show each IpTestAddress together with its PingStatus.

```
class PingTestResult
{
    public IPAddress IpAddress {get; set;}   // or maybe it is a string
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public string PingStatus {get; set;}
}
```

Code to create a sequence of PingTestResults:

```
IEnumerable<IpTestAddress> ipTestAddresses = this.GetIpTestAddresses();
var pingTestResults = ipTestAddresses
    .Select(ipTestAddress => new PingTestResult
    {
        IpAddress = ipTestAddress.IpAddress,
        Description = ipTestAddress.Description,
        PingStatus = this.GetPingStatus(ipTestAddress.IpAddress),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Until now we haven't used your DataGridView. To show it in your datagridview you will have declared some [DataGridViewColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn?view=net-5.0). Every DataGridViewColumn has a property [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=net-5.0). This holds the name of the property that should be shown in this column.

```
DataGridView dgvPingTestResults = new DataGridView();
DataGridViewColumn columnIpAddress = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewColumn columnDescription = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewColumn columnPingStatus = new DataGridViewColumn();
// TODO: Add columns to dgvPingTestresults.Columns

columnIpAddress.DataPropertyName = nameof(PingTestResult.IpAdddress);
columnDescription.DataPropertyName = nameof(PingTestResult.Description);
columnPingStatus.DataPropertyName = nameof(PingTestResult.PingStatus);
```

Now all you have to do is attach your pingTestResults to the DataGridView:

```
dgvPingTestResults.DataSource = pingTestResults;
```

Et voilà, your test results are shown.

This is display only. changes made by the operator are not updated in your original list.

If you want automatic updates, you should put your data in an object that implements IBindingList, like [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1)

```
dgvPingTestResults.DataSource = new BindingList<PingTestResult>(pingTestResults);
```

Now all changes that the operator makes: changes to the cells, added or removed rows are automatically updated to the BindingList.

To make efficient use of this feature, consider to add the following properties:

```
// Get set all displayed PingTestResults:
BindingList<PingTestResult> DisplayedTestResults
{
    get => (BindingList<PingTestResult>) this.dgvPingTestResults.DataSource;
    set => this.dgvPingTestResults.DataSource = value;
}

// Get the PingTestResult in the current row:
PingTestResult CurrentTestResult => this.dgvPingTestResult.CurentCell?
    .OwningRow.DataBoundItem as PingTestResult;

// Get all selected PingTestResults:
IEnumerable<PingTestResult> SelectedTestResults => this.dgvPinttestResult.SelectedRows
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<PingTestResult>();

// Get the PingTestResult of a row
PingTestResult GetPingTestResult(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    return (PingTestresult)row.DataBoundItem;
}
PingTestResult GetPingTestResult(int rowIndex)
{
    return this.GetPingTestResult(this.dgvPingTestResults.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
}

// Update the PingTestResult in a certain Row:
void UpdatePingTestResult(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    PingTestResult pingTestResult = GetPingTestResult(row));
    pingTestResult.PingStatus = GetPingstatus(pingTestResult.IpAddress);
}
```

Of course, the operator shouldn't be able to edit the value of the PingStatus:

```
columnPingStatus.ReadOnly = true;
```

Now after these methods, most event handlers will be one-liners:

If the operator clicks on a ping status, the ping status should be updates:

```
private void PingTestResults_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == this.columnPingStatus)
    {
        this.UpdatePingTestResult(this.dgvPingTestResults.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
    }
}
```

Or update all PingTestResults after clicking a button:

```
void ButtonRefreshAll_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    foreach (PingTestResult pingTestResult in this.DisplayedTestResults)
    {
         pingTestResult.PingStatus = GetPingstatus(pingTestResult.IpAddress);
    }
}
```

Of if the operator changes the IpAddress:

```
void CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex = this.columnIpAddress.DisplayIndex))
    {
        // Ip address edited; update the PingStatus
        this.UpdatePingTestResult(this.dgvPingTestResults.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit more than I anticipated from your view.
The dropdrop at the top is what the user selects what location to bring up it's devices in the datagridview.
After it populates all the devices via SQL query, I want them to be able to press that "Play" button and it'll constantly pinging those devices updated that static column for "Status". The status is not in the DB.